# How to hide default entries from create datalist menu in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I need to hide some entries from create datalist menu, such as Meeting Agenda, Task List, etc. 
Is there any way to do this?

Alfresco-4.2.d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing ,which you need to consider is your alfresco version, as in the latest version of alfresco there are many changes.We should always put alfresco version in question.

In alfresco version 4 or in nearer version you can consider below.
Major code changes will be in Alfresco.component.DataList object(Component) of YUI.

Files which needs to be changed.

> 1.datalist.get.html.ftl(tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\data-lists)
>
> 2.datalist.js(\tomcat\webapps\share\components\data-lists\datalist.js)

You may also need to edit below file
(\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\data-lists\forms\datalist-new.ftl)

Comment: Thank you, you answer was a great help for me. I end up with editing datalists.get.js. I just replaced remote.call("/api/classes/dl_dataListItem/subclasses") by remote.call("/api/classes/my_custom_base_type_here/subclasses").